# List a specific item and display values Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, cycle

I would like to ask how to improve the following code. I extract the brands of cars from the database, and then write them in the index template. If a user clicks on a specific brand, only the cars of that brand are displayed. I would like to improve the code using variables or a cycle, and I need help in doing so, therefore I attached at least a minimal working example of what I have already written.

**CarController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::latest()->get();
        $carsgroup = Car::whereNotNull('znacka')->groupBy('znacka')->orderBy('znacka', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('cars.index')
            ->with('cars', $cars)
            ->with('carsgroup', $carsgroup);

        }

public function renault()
    {
        $cars = Car::select()->where('znacka', 'Renault')->get();
        $carsgroup = Car::whereNotNull('znacka')->groupBy('znacka')->orderBy('znacka', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('cars.index')
            ->with('cars', $cars)
            ->with('carsgroup', $carsgroup);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="list-group mb-5">
         <a href="{{url('cars')}}" class="list-group-item">Vše</a>
            @foreach($carsgroup as $group)
               <a href="{{str_replace('S','Š',ucfirst(strtolower($group->znacka))) }}" class="list-group-item">{{ $group->znacka }}</a>
            @endforeach
         </div>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('Renault', 'CarController@renault');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes/web.php` you can add an `additional parameter` like this. If you want another url structure, you may have to adjust it a bit:

```
Route::get('cars/{brand}', 'CarController@carsbybrand');
```

This `parameter` can be accesses like this in your `controller`:

```
public function carsbybrand( $brand )
{
    $cars = Car::select()->where('znacka', $brand)->get();
    $carsgroup = Car::whereNotNull('znacka')->groupBy('znacka')->orderBy('znacka', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('cars.index')
        ->with('cars', $cars)
        ->with('carsgroup', $carsgroup);
}
```